# How to use Bundle Method in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, resourcebundle

I am creating an quiz app, after answering all the question in `main.xml` layout I want to show the result in `report.xml` as output.

I am not able to refer `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and `setContentView(R.layout.report)`in Main.java, then I heard about Bundle that we can pass the value in it and use it in another Activity. I tried a lot but I could'nt make it.

Comment: What you tried? post it

Comment: You can follow this tutorial :-[Demo Application Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to send multiple data from one activity to other

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                namevalue=name.getText().toString();
                overvalue=over.getText().toString();
                audiostatus=audio.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.this,home.class);
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                 bundle.putString( "namevalue",namevalue);  
                 bundle.putString("overvalue",overvaluse);
                 bundle.putInt("value",variablename);
                 intent.putExtras(bundle);   
                 startActivity(intent);                 
                }
            });
```

And also follow this link http://congeritc.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-passing-values-between-views.html

Comment: If my post solved your problem, please accept the answer then it will helps for others...